# Facebook Enhanced Auth Dialog not Appearing when User is Not Logged In

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-authentication

If a user follows a link to my Facebook application (apps.facebook.com/instantinternetstar) and they are not currently logged into Facebook they are allowed to enter the Application instead of being prompted to 1st log into Facebook and 2nd grant permissions via Auth Dialog.

If a User is logged into Facebook, the new Enhanced Auth Dialog works perfectly and always.

Is there a variable I have missed?

Answer (score 0):

Your settings may be fine.  What you can do on the default page of http://instantinternetstar.com is to query the http post parameter called `signed_request`, decode it and it will tell you if the user is authenticated or not.  Then you can display something to them so they know what you're about, before they take their time to login to Facebook, then accept your app.